# How to extract the filename extension and check it against an array of allowed extensions?

Tags: php

How to prepare subject string to fake preg_match checking extension from `$allowed` array? The goal is use filename with extension which is not in allowed array. I tried some trick like UTF8 coding and new line injection but couldn't achieve task goal. Thank You and sorry for my english

```
    $allowed = array('tst', 'dll');
$filename = basename($test);
if (preg_match('#\.(.+)$#', $filename, $matches) && isset($matches[1]) && !in_array($matches[1], $allowed))
    die("Extension not allowed!");

echo $ext;
```

Comment: If you have access to those files you can use `FileInfo` in order to check their mime types (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php). If not or that's not your goal - you can simply use: `$ext = last(explode(".", $filename))`.

Comment: In most cases, you'd want to check the file type, rather than the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

`pathinfo` is what you're looking for

[PHP.net](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

```
$file_parts = pathinfo($filename);

switch($file_parts['extension'])
{
    case "jpg":
    break;

    case "exe":
    break;

    case "": // Handle file extension for files ending in '.'
    case NULL: // Handle no file extension
    break;
}
```

This should be a good example to go further with.

Comment: Thank it is great answer

Comment: You're welcome. Be sure to mark this answer as the answer to your post so people know it's solved :).